# In Firefox, how can I filter and extract multiple links located within multiple open tabs?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, tabs

Here is my situation. I have 100 tabs open in **Firefox**. Within each tab is 20 unique URLs. I only need 10 of these links. This adds up to 1000 unique URLs I need extracted into a text list, so I can copy paste into another program to open them all at once in Firefox as separate tabs.

I'm looking for a way to quickly apply a filter and search within these 100 tabs to output a list of the 1000 unique URLs. Currently I've only found addons similar to one called [LinkGopher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/link-gopher/) They are only able to filter from 1 tab at a time. I need an addon that can filter links **WITHIN ALL** open tabs.

Comment: Hi, do you have any coding knowledge?

Comment: No unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm then I believe you could try iMacros or Selenium IDE. You can run a Macros that includes all the steps needed for one tab and finish it by moving to the next one. But I can't help you alot given that I usually code a small script for stuff like this.

Comment: Out of curiosity what type of coding language should I learn if I wanted create this script myself? JavaScript? I dabbled in Python a few years ago over at codeacademy, but lost interest. Creating scripts is something I'd find most useful because I run into a lot of problems like the one I mentioned here, where I want to automate something to save hours of repetitive actions only to achieve 1 simple result.

Comment: People code this scripts in a bunch of high level languages like Javascipt, Java, C# or python. Personally I use Python3+Selenium+Firefox. It's way easier to learn a language by doing than by just studying. If you have an objective then it should be easy to prototype something, baby steps are the key.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend learning JavaScript and then building a custom UserScript in [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/?src=search) or [Tampermonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/). These tools are designed specifically to let you analyze and manipulate the content of web pages, as well as [loading/saving user preferences](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM.setValue), and even [opening new tabs](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM.openInTab), which is exactly what you need.

If you're new to coding, this probably sounds quite daunting, and honestly, it won't be easy. But your friends over at Stack Overflow can help if you have any specific issues along the way. :)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but I faced the same issue, and I think I have found a solution. Maybe it can still help you too: https://superuser.com/a/1807716/1841218

Comment: If it is a dupplicate question, mark it as dupplicate.

Comment: @Toto, it cant as it has no accepted answer.

Comment: @RohitGupta: Sure, but he answered to himself so he can accept.

Comment: I can't accept it yet. I'll post here when I have.

Comment: I have accepted my own answer.